# Executing stored procedure from PHP results in "could not find stored procedure"

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Not able to run my code due to the error

> Could not find stored procedure

But I have created it in SQL Server and also in Visual Studio and all my connections are correct.

Checked all the data connections with the code and database.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getLogin(string email, string password)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Register", con))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@txtemail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@txtpassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "login";
            cmd.Connection = con;

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            // con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            da.Fill(ds);

            HttpContext.Current.Session["email"] = email;

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented);
        }
    }  
}
```

Executing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` returns an exception:

> Could not find stored procedure

Comment: Does the user account you are using in the connection string have access to the stored proc? Also, generally speaking the use of `sp_` as a preffix to a stored proc is a no-no as it infers a global "Special" type of procedure held in the `Master` DB

Comment: Specifically non-db-owner users will not have execute permission on custom stored procs unless it is granted to them.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a problem of permissions , is the user used to connect your app to the Db is the same you used to create the stored proc?

Comment: It makes no difference who created the stored proc if the connecting login doesn't have execute permissions or access to the containing schema.